# Allow only one of checkbox selected on tableview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I added checkbox inside of tableview But I don't know how to **set these checkbox to allow only one of them is selected** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2eWl.png)

Here is one of my code for column *Selection*

```
selectcol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,Boolean>("Select"));
```

and This is Usermaster code

```
 public class Usermaster {
....
   public CheckBox Select=new CheckBox();

....
    public CheckBox getSelect() {
    return Select;
}
public void setSelect(CheckBox Select) {
    this. Select=Select;
}
```

Comment: You will need to listen for a `Usermaster` to be selected and then use a loop to manually unselect the rest.

Comment: Good call, @Paul.

Comment: @Zephyr actually this only works for radio-buttons. I've just checked the documentation on `CheckBox` and it doesn't override `ToggleButton` for some reason

Answer (score 4):

Checkboxes meant to indicate to the user that multiple options can be selected. If you want to allow only a single selection, why don't you use [radio buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/radio-button.htm) which are the standard way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for ur idea I bet we have solution for checkbox I did use checkboxgroup with JavaSwing And it easy to be solved . To javafx its not the same thing

Comment: If you must use checkboxes you can just unselect all other checkboxes when one is selected. But the correct solution is to use a Control that is designed for single selection such as radio button or select dropdown.